# Visual Studio projects not accessible within solution

Tags: visual-studio

So I've seen this problem come up and asked about here but I still can't seem to get my solution to compile.  It's the weirdest thing.

I have a multi project solution:

- Services
- Domain
- Repository
- Infrastructure
- Application
- website.

I was cruising along on the project and, one day, I cranked up the pc and started VS2010.  Pressed <kbd>F5</kbd> to start up the website and started getting some errors that weren't there the day before.

The things it was complaining about like single argument constructors that it thought didn't exist but both me and intellisense knew it did.  Any changes I make to the other projects don't seem to be recognized by the compiler.

I've tried doing the clean thing.  The solution and each project but nothing.  I also blew away the solution and recreated it and still the same error.  I even copied the project and tried it on another PC with VS2010 and still the same problem.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the output from one of the projects I rebuilt.  There's a warning.  Not sure how significant it is:

```
------ Rebuild All started: Project: FoodTruck.Infrastructure, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
  FoodTruck.Infrastructure -> C:\Users\eric.downey\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FoodTruck\FoodTruck\FoodTruck.Infrastructure\bin\Debug\FoodTruck.Infrastructure.dll
------ Rebuild All started: Project: FoodTruck.Domain, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
  FoodTruck.Domain -> C:\Users\eric.downey\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FoodTruck\FoodTruck\FoodTruck.Domain\bin\Debug\FoodTruck.Domain.dll
------ Rebuild All started: Project: FoodTruck.Services, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
  FoodTruck.Services -> C:\Users\eric.downey\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FoodTruck\FoodTruck\FoodTruck.Services\bin\Debug\FoodTruck.Services.dll
------ Rebuild All started: Project: FoodTruck.Infrastructure.Repository, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "log4net", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.
  FoodTruck.Infrastructure.Repository -> C:\Users\eric.downey\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FoodTruck\FoodTruck\FoodTruck.Infrastructure.Repository\bin\Debug\FoodTruck.Infrastructure.Repository.dll
========== Rebuild All: 4 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Check that your project build order is correct and that [all projects are being built](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz9kefa.aspx). Also, go to the "final" project's output directory (the website?) and check that the appropriate DLLs for each of the sub-projects are there. Just to check the obvious... Have you got the appropriate references to other projects? Are the assemblies set to Copy always / Copy if newer?

Comment: Have you tried going into each project's folder and deleting the contents of the obj folder?

Comment: hmm. weird. have a look at the output window as you rebuild each project separately, what does it say? (start with projects which have least amount of dependencies to other). if you haven't been convinced before to use some form of source control like svn or git, I think you will very soon.

Comment: I'm normally opposed to posting huge chunks of information in a question - but in this case, the contents of the build output window for the first build after you clean the solution would probably help us track this down fairly quickly

Comment: @Basic: Looking at the build order it appears everything is check for being built.  How do I verify if assemblies are set to copy always/copy newer?

Comment: @Josh: I've blown away all of the obj folders on each of the projects and forced a rebuild of each project individually.

Comment: Go to the "parent" project and make sure that "Show all files" is turned on (one of the icons across the top of solution explorer). Expand the references node and find your child project. Look at the properties window. In this case you want `Copy Local = True`

Comment: Added detail from output window from a rebuild of one of the projects to the end of my original post.

Comment: @Basic: the parent project is actually a website.  When I click on the website project I don't get the 'show all files' like I do for a class library project.

Comment: @user1572 I'm using VS2012 but I've just set up a new MVC4 project and have "Show all files". Same is true for setting up a new ASP.Net Webforms site. If you happen to be using the old-school "Website" which is just based on a directory structure and has no actual project then I don't know, I haven't touched that in years. I strongly recommend you read [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx) `We recommend that you choose web application projects. ... web site projects have some advantages, ... the disadvantages outweigh any perceived advantages.`

Comment: Consider upping the verbosity of the build system... `Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run->MSBuild Project build output verbosity`. Set it to `Normal` and repeat the clean/build.

Comment: Thanks everyone - I resolved the issue.  I had a class in my domain project called PasswordReset which was used to store password reset requests.  Apparently you can't have an object named that :(